# Notifying the Parent widget that error happened in loading data in asynchronous, child widgets

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a stateful child widget that it's main job is to load data from a dataset asynchronously, wraps the data in some container, create a future builder and hand it over to the parent widget. Then in the parent widget, I want to check for the errors in the child widget, in case that there was a problem loading something from the database and finally, if everything was ok, I want to add the child to a **ListView** and if not, ignore the whole process (adding nothing to the List). I am devastated to implement this fairly straightforward concept.

Some of the approaches I tried and failed:

- looked for an empty widget of some sort to return from the child and check for it in the parent. *Did not work, I couldn't find an empty widget in flutter docs, plus it looks sorta messy.*
- Tried sending the parent's `setState` method as a callback to the child in order to add the item if everything was ok. *Did not work*, I couldn't pass the child object itself to add, also again, looks kinda messy.

Basic code:

```dart
class Items extends StatefulWidget {
  const Items({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemsState createState() => _ItemsState();
}

class _ItemsState extends State<Items> {

  var attributes;

  Future<bool> readFromDataBase(){
    ...
    final data = await db.read();

    if (data == 'valid'){
      attributes = data;
      return true;

    else throw error;
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      FutureBuilder(future: readFromDataBase,
      builder: (context , snapshot){
        if(snapshot is connected)
          return Text(attributes);

        else if (snapshot thrown error)
            ->TELL PARENT TO NOT TO ADD THE ELEMENT TO THE LIST
        )
      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you creating a widget that its purpose to load data but not display it, why not handle that job in the parent widget?

Comment: @Adnan well, I know that what you say is the right thing to do, but I wanted to see if I can make this work before refactoring the whole parent's code.

Comment: well, the best way to achieve what you are asking for is using a state management method. I'd recommend taking a look at https://pub.dev/packages/provider, this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFxk_KJCqgk explains it very well.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a method in parent object that you can call from child object..

Something like errorOccurred(X, y, z) and call from child and store in a list directly in parent class ..
You can also pass a function to the constructor of child object to call when an error occur like this :

new yourChildClass(onErrorFunction)

Then in your parent object u define that onErrorFunction

Let me know if this helps you

Comment: I don't think it is possible as the child class works async. If it was synchronous it would probably work. On the other hand, currently, I'm trying to send a promise (Future) to the child and check to see if it gets resolved or no but I couldn't find any way to create an empty promise yet.

Comment: It's not a problem to call synchronous methods from asynchronous tasks.. your parent object is still or is being disposed after asynchronous tasks? If it is still and usable, so it's not disposable, when the async task is running and an error occur you can easily call the parent method and display the error

Comment: It's not disposable. The problem is the process of deciding to add the returned widget to the list or no. I'll try to add some code in order to demonstrate the situation better.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your `ChildWidget` to accept `onError` callback in the constructor, and call the `onError` callback when the future is completed with error, as follows:

```
class ParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ParentWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  void onErrorOccuredInChildWidget() {
    //Do some error hadding stuff
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChildWidget(onErrorOccured: onErrorOccuredInChildWidget);
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onErrorOccured;
  ChildWidget({Key? key, required this.onErrorOccured}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
        future:
            databaseCall, // async function which returns the list of futures.
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            onErrorOccured();
            return Container();
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                //build your list view here
                );
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```